GDAL with ECW support on Ubuntu
I'm trying to install GDAL with ECW support on Ubuntu 22.04.4, but I'm getting an error I can't figure out after running the "make" command below. This is an extract from the error:
/usr/bin/ld: /home/as1233/gdal-3.1.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `NCSFreeFileInfo'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/as1233/gdal-3.1.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `NCS::CThreadPool::CJob::LockStatus()'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/as1233/gdal-3.1.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `NCS::CView::GetParameterInternal(char const*, __va_list_tag*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/as1233/gdal-3.1.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `NCS::CString::CString()'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/ld/home/as1233/gdal-3.1.3/.libs/libgdal.so: : undefined reference to `/home/as1233/gdal-3.1.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `NCS::CThreadPool::CJob::LockStatus()NCS::CView::GetCompressionMemoryRequirementsBytes()'
/usr/bin/ld'
: /home/as1233/gdal-3.1.3/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `NCS::CView::SetParameter(char const*, ...)'

I followed the steps from this tutorial Installing QGIS with ECW support on ubuntu 20.04:

Downloaded the ECW SDK 5.5 from Hexagon (that's the only version currently available) and run the bin file
Copied the installed files to /usr/local/hexagon
Made symbolic link to libs like libNCSEcw.so.**

sudo ln -s /usr/local/hexagon/lib/cpp11abi/x64/release/* /usr/local/lib/

Downloaded and installed PROJ version
Downloaded and compiled GDAL. I tried both versions 3.5.3 and 3.1.3

./configure --with-ecw=/usr/local/hexagon
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=//usr/local/hexagon/lib/cpp11abi/x64/release:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo make
I got the error above after running the "make" command.
How do I get this to work?
This issue deals with the same error https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2657. I'm not sure if it's helpful.
